# Using glmnet to find optimized model for a given number of predictors

Tags: r, statistics, glmnet

I'm attempting to use LASSO for a slightly different function than originally designed. I have a 22 different tasks on a test, which, when averaged, produce a final score. I want to see which combination of a limited number of tasks would best predict the overall score with the hopes of creating a short form of this test.

I'm using glmnet to run the lasso next, and it runs as expected. I can then easily find the model at a given lamda with

```
coef(cvfit, s = s)
```

However, I am wondering if it would be possible to specify the n of predictors that have non-zero coefficients, rather than the penalization parameter?

I've set up a very inefficient way of doing this as shown below by extracting the models from a grid of test lambdas, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this

```
nvar <- list()
coeffs <- list()

for(j in 1:20000) {

  s <- j / 20000

  coeffs[j] <- coef(cvfit, s = s) ##Get coefficient list at given lamda

  nvar[j] <- sum(as.vector(coef(cvfit, s = s)) != 0) - 1 ##Count number of variables with non-zero coeff and subtract one because intercept is always non-zero

}

nvar <- unlist(nvar)

getlamda <- function(numvar = 4) {

  min.lambda <- min(lambdas[nvar == numvar]) / 20000 ##Find the smallest lambda which resulted in the given number of non-zero coefficients

  coeffs[min.lambda]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing with Blended's solution above, I realized that there is an even simpler way of doing this.

Using the Boston dataset used in the example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(glmnet)

(boston <- MASS::Boston %>% tbl_df())

tr_x <- model.matrix(medv ~ ., data = boston)[,-1]
tr_y <- boston$medv
cvfit <- glmnet(tr_x, tr_y)
```

The `cvfit` object already has all the components we need to find the answer for a given number of variables. `df` is the number of degrees of freedom, and is the number of variable parameter in which we are interested. `lambda` is the lambda for each model.

So we can create a simple function that returns the best model for a given number of variables.

```
get_nparam <- function(mod, numvar) {

  coef(mod, s = with(cvfit, min(lambda[df == numvar])))

}

get_nparam(cvfit, 4)

#14 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#                       1
#(Intercept) 15.468034114
#crim         .          
#zn           .          
#indus        .          
#chas         .          
#nox          .          
#rm           3.816165372
#age          .          
#dis          .          
#rad          .          
#tax          .          
#ptratio     -0.606026131
#black        0.001518042
#lstat       -0.495954410
#
```

Thanks again to Blender for a different solution and putting me on the path to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowSums()`.

```
(boston <- MASS::Boston %>% tbl_df())
#> # A tibble: 506 x 14
#>       crim    zn indus  chas   nox    rm   age   dis   rad   tax ptratio
#>  *   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 0.00632  18    2.31     0 0.538  6.58  65.2  4.09     1   296    15.3
#>  2 0.0273    0    7.07     0 0.469  6.42  78.9  4.97     2   242    17.8
#>  3 0.0273    0    7.07     0 0.469  7.18  61.1  4.97     2   242    17.8
#>  4 0.0324    0    2.18     0 0.458  7.00  45.8  6.06     3   222    18.7
#>  5 0.0690    0    2.18     0 0.458  7.15  54.2  6.06     3   222    18.7
#>  6 0.0298    0    2.18     0 0.458  6.43  58.7  6.06     3   222    18.7
#>  7 0.0883   12.5  7.87     0 0.524  6.01  66.6  5.56     5   311    15.2
#>  8 0.145    12.5  7.87     0 0.524  6.17  96.1  5.95     5   311    15.2
#>  9 0.211    12.5  7.87     0 0.524  5.63 100    6.08     5   311    15.2
#> 10 0.170    12.5  7.87     0 0.524  6.00  85.9  6.59     5   311    15.2
#> # ... with 496 more rows, and 3 more variables: black <dbl>, lstat <dbl>,
#> #   medv <dbl>
```

For above dataset ([Boston housing](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/Boston.html)), consider `medv ~ .`.

```
library(glmnet)
tr_x <- model.matrix(medv ~ ., data = boston)[,-1]
tr_y <- boston$medv
cvfit <- glmnet(tr_x, tr_y)

head(t(coef(cvfit)))
    #> 6 x 14 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
    #>    [[ suppressing 14 column names '(Intercept)', 'crim', 'zn' ... ]]
    #>                                                        
    #> s0 22.53281 . . . . . .         . . . . . .  .         
    #> s1 23.60072 . . . . . .         . . . . . . -0.08439977
    #> s2 23.67264 . . . . . 0.1278413 . . . . . . -0.15358093
    #> s3 21.44649 . . . . . 0.5694424 . . . . . . -0.19698136
    #> s4 19.42057 . . . . . 0.9714620 . . . . . . -0.23654740
    #> s5 17.57464 . . . . . 1.3377669 . . . . . . -0.27259852
```

I guess you have done this procedure.

---

### Remarks

1. It might be convenient to *transpose* the coefficient matrix so that each variable becomes each column.
2. For `t(coef(cvfit))`, `rowSums(t(coef(cvfit)) != 0)` finds the number of non-zero element for each variable.
3. Next, we just match `numvar` with this `rowSums` and find the value of coefficient.

Denote that from `s0` to `s5`, lambda `s0` is larger than `s5` - more penalized.

```
head(cvfit$lambda)
#> [1] 6.777654 6.175546 5.626927 5.127046 4.671574 4.256564
```

---

### Subset coef with numvar

Based on these facts,

```
get_nparam <- function(mod, numvar) {
  beta <- coef(mod)
  non_zero <- rowSums(t(beta)[,-1] != 0) # ignore intercept
  min_lam <- which(non_zero == numvar) # numvar non-zero coef
  t(beta)[dplyr::last(min_lam),] # last index = smallest lambda
}
```

With this function, you can get

```
get_nparam(cvfit, 4)
#>  (Intercept)         crim           zn        indus         chas 
#> 15.468034114  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000 
#>          nox           rm          age          dis          rad 
#>  0.000000000  3.816165372  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000 
#>          tax      ptratio        black        lstat 
#>  0.000000000 -0.606026131  0.001518042 -0.495954410
```

`rm`, `ptratio`, `black`, and `lstat` are non-zero while the others zero.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply with clear step-by-step instructions and especially the replicable example. I think I figured out an even simpler solution after playing with your code, which I will post below.